# I want to change for to while

Tags: python

I want to write this code using `while` loop, not `for` loop
I tried doing everything, turning dict to list and then removing items but it didn't work.

```
Journal = {12: 'ASUS', 2: 'HP', 57: 'IBM', 3: 'DELL', 689: 'APPLE'}
inputi = input("five keys ").split(",")
num = len(inputi)
for keys, values in list(Journal.items()):
     Journal.pop(keys)
     num -= 1
     Journal[inputi[num]] = values
```

Comment: If the For loop works, why change it to a While loop?

Comment: What is this code actually supposed to do?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to swap keys that point to a given value, can you give some context of what `Journal` should look like at the end of a sample of keys?

Comment: Also, is `Journal` only supposed to contain 5 keys?

Comment: I want to change it, im still learning and want to understand while loop better. It gives new keys to Journal dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

### Original For-Loop:

```
for keys, values in list(Journal.items()):
     Journal.pop(keys)
     num -= 1
     Journal[inputi[num]] = values
```

### A While-Loop Equivalent:

```
jit = Journal.items()
while(True):
     try:
         key, value = next(jit)
     except StopIteration:
         break
     Journal.pop(key)
     num -= 1
     Journal[inputi[num]] = value
```